# How to specify directories to isort with config file?

Tags: python, isort

How can I specify which files to sort using isort using only the config file? I want to be able to `isort .` and have it only pick up certain target directories. I'm using pyproject.toml and i've tried

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
src_paths = ["src", "test"]
```

and

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
sources = ["src", "test"]
```

and

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
directory = ["src", "test"]
```

to no avail

Comment: Looks like you have the same as their documentation. I recommend posting directly in the github repo

Comment: first block should be work but looks like the docs is outdated: https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options

Answer (score 3):

I have checked source code of `isort` am afraid this is as of now it's not possible.

Closest you can get is when using [pipenv shortcuts](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts) (ofc if used pipenv as package manager) and setup isort shortcut in `Pipfile`, like:

```
[scripts]
isort = "isort src tests"
```

And then call `isort` using `pipenv run isort` which will fix all files in both `src` and `tests` dirs.

You can as well chain the scripts, so you can e.g. define second script `isort_check` in `Pipfile`, which will just check and not correct `isort` issues:

```
[scripts]
isort = "isort src test"
isort_check = "pipenv run isort --check-only --diff --color"
```

Usage will be `pipenv run isort_check` which proves configuration of directories is defined just in one place ([Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) principle.)

Comment: looks like the docs is outdated: https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options

Answer (score -1):

I can skip everything but those directories

```
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
skip_glob = "^(src|tests)"
```

Comment: It does not work as the glob matching is done by fnmatch and not by regex